# Showing bytes as hexadecimal escapes rather than octal escapes

Tags: display, characters, escape

Short version: Can I make Emacs show `\ff` or `\xff` instead of `\377`?

Long version: Suppose you open a file that is not entirely text and has some binary data (say a PostScript or PDF file). For example, suppose you open [GNU Emacs Reference Card (PDF)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf).

[image: Screenshot of Emacs (Aquamacs) viewing refcard.pdf]

Then, for bytes outside the ASCII printable range (32–126),

- Emacs shows the "high" bytes (bytes with value 128 to 255) as octal escape sequences: 128 is shown as `\200`, 129 is shown as `\201`, …, 255 is shown as `\377`.
- Emacs shows the bytes 0 to 31 (other than byte 9 which is shown as a tab not `^I`, and byte 10 which is shown as a newline not `^J`) as a caret followed by the character that is 64 ahead: byte 0 is shown as `^@`, byte 1 is shown as `^A`, …, byte 26 is shown as `^Z`, byte 27 is shown as `^[`, …, byte 31 is shown as `^_`. Also, Emacs shows byte 127 as `^?`.

I know that the reason Emacs shows octal is historical: at some point a few decades ago, octal was more commonly in use. (For example, `man ascii` starts with octal first, and TeX supports octal escape sequences.) But as octal is less useful than hexadecimal these days (e.g. to compare with the output of `hexdump` or Python byte-string representations), I'd like to see hexadecimal escape sequences. How can I change this?

(Note: the octal escape sequences are shown highlighted instead of looking like regular text, and of course it's not possible to step "into" the escape character (i.e. hitting `C-f` at the point before `\343` takes you to the point after `\343`); I'd like to retain this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with [display tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Tables.html#Display-Tables). This may be a little clumsy and I haven't investigated how this might interfere with packages that use display tables for their own purposes, but the basic use case works.

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(setq standard-display-table (make-display-table))
(cl-loop
 for x from 128 to 255
 do (aset standard-display-table x
      (cl-map 'vector
          (lambda (c) (make-glyph-code c 'escape-glyph))
          (format "\\%02x" x))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful so I'm accepting this. I had to make some minor changes which are in [my answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33117/showing-bytes-as-hexadecimal-escapes-rather-than-octal-escapes#33129); please take a look and let me know if I should correct anything.

Answer (score 10):

**edit**: With Emacs 26.1 or later, it's a `(setq display-raw-bytes-as-hex t)` away.

No, you can't.  The display of unprintables above the printable ASCII range is hardcoded in `xdisp.c`:

```
if (CHAR_BYTE8_P (c))
  /* Display \200 instead of \17777600.  */
  c = CHAR_TO_BYTE8 (c);
len = sprintf (str, "%03o", c + 0u);
```

[I sent a patch fixing this to debbugs](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=27122).

Comment: "No, you can't" is wrong, see [Gilles' suggestion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33117/showing-bytes-as-hexadecimal-escapes-rather-than-octal-escapes#comment51136_33117), but +1 anyway for giving a patch to fix this properly.

Comment: Huh, just when I thought you can't hack your way around this one, someone else proves me wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Oh nice, wonderful! Getting a patch into Emacs is not entirely impossible it appears. :-) Thanks for your work… look forward to this being released in Emacs 26.

Comment: Works great in Emacs 26! Thanks!!! (You may want to edit your answer now.)

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out thanks to [the answer by Gilles](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33117/showing-bytes-as-hexadecimal-escapes-rather-than-octal-escapes/33124#33124) and the 2010/2011 thread on `gnu.emacs.help` called “How switch from escaped octal character code to escaped HEX?” ([Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/UeVx_4fywd4), [Nabble](http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/How-switch-from-escaped-octal-character-code-to-escaped-HEX-td70854.html)).

The details of how Emacs displays characters are in the section [Display > Text Display (“How Text Is Displayed”)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Display.html#Text-Display) of the Emacs manual (<kbd>C-h r</kbd>), and section [Display > Character Display](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Display.html#Character-Display) of the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual. The thing to do is to change the [display table](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Tables.html#Display-Tables) for the characters 128 to 255 (and whatever other characters one wants displayed as hexadecimal escapes).

I had to make two minor changes from the answer by Gilles:

1. Instead of something like

   ```
   (aset standard-display-table 128 [?\\ ?8 ?0])
   ```

   I had to use something like

   ```
   (aset standard-display-table (unibyte-char-to-multibyte 128) [?\\ ?8 ?0])
   ```
2. Setting `standard-display-table` isn't always enough, because some modes (like `global-whitespace-mode`) may mess it up. And then it appears you need to set `buffer-display-table` instead.

So instead I made an interactive function that I can invoke when I want the display to change in a specific buffer.

```el
(defun use-hex-not-octal ()
  "Use hexadecimal escape sequences instead of octal."
  (interactive)
  (require 'cl-lib)
  (unless buffer-display-table
    (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table)))
  (setq unprintable (append (number-sequence 127 255) (number-sequence 0 8) (number-sequence 11 31)))
  (cl-loop
   for x in unprintable
   do (aset buffer-display-table (unibyte-char-to-multibyte x)
            (cl-map 'vector
                    (lambda (c) (make-glyph-code c 'escape-glyph))
                    (format "\\%02x" x)))))
```

With this, if I open [`refcard.pdf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf) and run <kbd>M-x use-hex-not-octal</kbd>, I get the following, for the same region as in the question:

[image: refcard.pdf with M-x use-hex-not-octal]

Answer (score 2):

Emacs' hexl mode should do what you want - it's a major mode which provides support for viewing and editing binary files.  Use  M-x hexl-find-file instead of C-x C-f to visit the file to get started.  More details can be found in the Emacs info manual, or at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Editing-Binary-Files.html.

Comment: No I don't want hexl mode: postscript files are mostly text with only occasional binary data, and it's not convenient to switch to hexl-mode and lose much text editing functionality. Let me add a screenshot to the question to clarify.

Comment: Ah, I know what you mean, but don't know of any easy way that you can change that. I suspect display tables might be involved somewhere...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion though. I didn't downvote btw!